# What is the meaning of Timestamp in QuestDb?

Tags: questdb

I'm a bit lost in QuestDb terminology, when I create a table

```
CREATE TABLE views (
username symbol,
name symbol,
ip_address symbol,
post_count long,
timestamp timestamp)
```

some part of documentation say that I need to add `timestamp(timestamp)`. What does timestamp mean other than a column type which I already specified in the above create table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Timestamp` is a column type and you correctly used it to define column named `timestamp`.

Also when a table is created there can be multiple columns of type timestamp. But there can be only one so called **designated** timestamp. This special column then makes all table rows stored in ordered by the designated timestamp values. If you are familiar with Oracle it is similar to index organised tables or clustered key in MsSql.

If you add `timestamp(timestamp)` at the end of your create table it will mean that column with name timestamp is the designated timestamp of the table